# フォームからメールが送信されない

Tags: centos, dns, sendmail, mail

環境
OS  CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
Apache  Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
postfix 2.6.6

ドメインをさくらで取得しており
webサーバのみ他社(AWS CloudFront+LB+LightSail,DNS:Route53)
メールはさくらのレンタルサーバ(プレミアム)を使用していました。

本日10頃にゾーン変更のAレコード及びネームサーバを変更する形でwebサーバのみさくらのVPSへ移し
web上のメールフォームからメールを送信しましたが正常にメールが配送されません。

maillogは以下の様になっています。

---

```
Sep 29 12:48:44 tk2-405-XXXXX postfix/pickup[11819]: 43504420A4: uid=48 from=<xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com>
Sep 29 12:48:44 tk2-405-XXXXX postfix/cleanup[12041]: 43504420A4: message-id=<20180929034844.43504420A4@tk2-xxx-xxxxxx.vs.sakura.ne.jp>
Sep 29 12:48:44 tk2-405-XXXXX postfix/smtp[12042]: warning: no MX host for xxxxxxxx.com has a valid address record
Sep 29 12:48:44 tk2-405-XXXXX postfix/smtp[12042]: 430204634B: to=<xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com>, relay=none, delay=0, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=xxxxx.sakura.ne.jp.xxxxxxxx.com type=AAAA: Host not found)
Sep 29 12:48:44 tk2-405-XXXXX postfix/qmgr[1474]: 43504420A4: from=<xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com>, size=4501, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 29 12:48:44 tk2-405-XXXXX postfix/qmgr[1474]: 430204634B: removed
```

---

ドメイン周りの設定は下記へ変更しております。

▼現在のドメインゾーン設定

```
エントリ名   タイプ データ
 @   NS  ns1.dns.ne.jp.
 NS  ns2.dns.ne.jp.
 A   さくらVPSサーバ　IP
 MX  10 @
 www     CNAME   @
 mail    CNAME   @
 ftp     CNAME   @
```

・Aレコードは本日10時頃変更いたしました。

▼現在のネームサーバ設定

```
ネームサーバ１ NS1.DNS.NE.JP
ネームサーバ２ NS2.DNS.NE.JP
ネームサーバ３
ネームサーバ４
```

・本日10頃に上記設定へ変更いたしました。

---

テスト時別ドメインをVPS上のサーバに割り当ててテストした際は
本日変更作業前にテストしましたが問題なくメールが配送されておりました。

本日上記以外に下記行っています。
・さくらで取得したテスト用ドメインのAレコードをさくらVPSのサーバIPから変更
・さくらVPS上のに構築したwebサーバのSSL証明書の入替え(本番ドメインへの変更)

DNS伝搬中に一時的に発生する問題でしょうか
何かお分かりになりましたらご回答をお願いできれば幸いです。

---

※9月29日16時現在
商用利用しており、長時間不具合を出したままに出来ない為、現在、ドメイン(ゾーン、ネームサーバ)を変更前の状態に戻しています。

Comment: dig コマンドがインストールされているのでしたら、`dig +noall +ans +nottl +nocl -t mx xxxxxxxx.com` を実行して表示される MX host の A レコードを `dig +noall +ans +nottl +nocl -t a MX_host` で確認していただけますか。

Comment: ご回答有難う御座います・
ご教示頂いたコマンドを打ってみました。

▼digコマンド結果
[xxxxxxx@tk2-405-xxxxx ~]$ dig +noall +ans +nottl +nocl -t mx xxxxxx.com
xxxxxx.com. MX      10 xxxxxx.sakura.ne.jp.
[xxxxxxx@tk2-405-xxxxx ~]$ dig +noall +ans +nottl +nocl -t a 10 xxxxxx.sakura.ne.jp.
xxxxxx.sakura.ne.jp. A     [さくらレンタルサーバ(プレミアム)IP]

商用利用しているサイトの為、現在設定を戻しました。
一部伝搬が完了していないのか　mxレコードは現在の『10 @』ではなく『10 xxxxxx.sakura.ne.jp.』で表示されました。

本日
mxレコードは
10 @
↓
10 xxxxxx.sakura.ne.jp
↓
10 @
変更しました。

Aレコードは
[さくらVPSサーバ]
↓
[さくらレンタルサーバ(プレミアム)IP]

ネームサーバは
[ ns1.dns.ne.jp.　　 NS  ns2.dns.ne.jp.]
↓
[AWS Route53]

へ戻しています。

Answer (score 1):

記入が遅れましたが自己解決できましたので、記載いたします。

・さくらのドメインのゾーン設定のMXレコードのルール・・・@を指定した場合はaレコードで指定したサーバを使う
・上記により内部配送が発生し結果メール配送がエラーになった

MXレコードを直接さくらのレンタルサーバを指定したところ、問題なくメールが配送されました。

Comment: 解決したようでよかったです。もしよければ、解決マークをつけてもらえますか？ マークを付けると、この質問のステータスが解決済みになります。